# how to use regex search to select on the names missing some numeric/character pattern

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a string which is something like this:

```
Hi_2T/2C_2016
Hi_4T/4C_2015
Hi_2T/4C_2017
Hi_2013
```

now i want to use a regex expression which when executed will give me following output:

```
Hi_2013
```

i.e it only finds something missing #T/#C information

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
grep '^Hi_[[:digit:]]\+[^T]' your_file.txt
```

That searches, starting at the beginning of every line, for `"Hi_"` followed by one or more digits, followed by a character that is NOT `T`.

Your question makes me wonder if you also might have things that look like this that you want to catch:

```
Hi_3T
```

That is, the `T` is there, but it's missing the `/..C...`.  If that's the case, you could do this:

```
grep -v '^Hi_[[:digit:]]\+T\/' your_file.txt
```

(The `-v` inverts the match...so it will show any lines that do NOT match the regex.)